# rules on convariance for templates

Tags: c++, templates, covariance

Why does `initializer_list<string> ls = {"A", "B", "C"};`  work?

The rhs is of `intializer_list<const char*>`, I wonder how is it converted to the lhs.

Similarly, how does `vector<string> vs = {"A", "B", "C"}` work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*The rhs is of `intializer_list<const char*>`*

This is wrong. Right hand side has no type. It is not an object of type `initializer_list`. It is *braced-init-list*, a special construct in language, used in several contexts.

**[dcl.init.list]/3** says this about your first question:

> List-initialization of an object or reference of type T is defined as follows:
>       [...]
>   — Otherwise, if `T` is a specialization of `std::initializer_list<E>`, a prvalue `initializer_list` object is constructed as described below and used to initialize the object according to the rules for initialization of an object from a class of the same type (8.5).

**[dcl.init.list]/5**:

> An object of type `std::initializer_list<E>` is constructed from an initializer list as if the implementation allocated a temporary array of *N* elements of type *const E*, where *N* is the number of elements in the `initializer list`. Each element of that array is copy-initialized with the corresponding element of the initializer list, and the `std::initializer_list<E>` object is constructed to refer to that array. *[ Note: A constructor or conversion function selected for the copy shall be accessible (Clause 11) in the context of the initializer list. —end note ]* If a narrowing conversion is required to initialize any of the elements, the program is ill-formed.

In short:

1. First it allocates memory for array of 3 strings
2. Then it tries to initialize each string with corresponding element from *init-list*. All elements of list are convertible to `const char*` and `std::string` has constructor accepting `const char*`, so it is used to construct those strings.

In your second question another clause from **[dcl.init.list]/3** is used:

> List-initialization of an object or reference of type T is defined as follows:
>       [...]
>   — Otherwise, if `T` is a class type, constructors are considered. The applicable constructors are enumerated and the best one is chosen through overload resolution (13.3, 13.3.1.7). If a narrowing conversion (see below) is required to convert any of the arguments, the program is ill-formed.

`vector<string>` has a constructor taking `initializer_list<string>`. It is a best match in this case and we are back to stage 1: we need to construct `initializer_list<string>` from *braced-init-list*, which we already know how to do.